# mysql prepared statment giving error

Tags: mysql

i am trying to write a stored procedure which updates the field of a table as specified in the argument .i am getting syntax error in @sql statment.please help

```
 create procedure new_upd1(ind int(3),attribute varchar(30),pk int(11),new_value varchar(30))
begin
    set @att=attribute;
    set @primk=pk;
    set @updated=new_value;

    if ind=1 then
        set @sql='update department set ?=? where departmentid=?';
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt using @att,@updated,@primk;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
    end if;
end
```

Comment: How are we suppose to know what syntax error is coming if you don't show the error message?

Comment: i m sorry, the cmd just says syntax error :(

Comment: it usually says in which line.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters don't work for column or table names, only for values. Do it like this:

```
create procedure new_upd1(ind int(3),attribute varchar(30),pk int(11),new_value varchar(30))
begin
    set @att=attribute;
    set @primk=pk;
    set @updated=new_value;

    if ind=1 then
        set @sql=CONCAT('update department set ', @att, '=? where departmentid=?;');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt using @updated,@primk;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
    end if;
end
```